# (JAVA) how to use charAt() to find last digit number (or rightmost) of any real number?

Tags: java

Hello Im new to programming
and as title I was wonder how you can find last digit of any given number?
for example when entering in 5.51123123 it will display 3
All I know is I should use charAt 
Should I use while loop?
thanks in advance

Comment: while loop may help, indeed. Or you can do it without a while loop, too.

Comment: You need to define "any given number".  Do you mean a character string containing the decimal representation of a number, or an `int` or `float` or whatever containing a numeric value?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to do something like this:

```
double number = 5.51123123;
String numString = number + "";
System.out.println(numString.charAt(numString.length()-1));
```

When you do the number + "", Java "coerces" the type of number from a double to a string and allows you to perform string functions on it.

The numString.length()-1 is because numString.length() returns the count of all the characters in the string BUT charAt() indexes into the string and its indexing begins at 0, so you need to do the -1 or you'll get a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: I really don't understand why my answer has two downvotes...it's what the guy is wanting :(

Comment: Ready-made answers to questions that include no attempted code are typically considered poor form.

Comment: when compiler sees things like `"" + aDouble`, what is does is translate it to `new StringBuilder("").append(aDouble).toString()`  for which in StringBuilder, appending a Double is in fact calling `String.valueOf(aDouble)` or something similar.  Therefore in such case, it is more preferable to simply do `String numstring = String.valueOf(number)` as most answer here is doing, which better shows the intention of the code, and also save unnecessary overhead

Comment: Thank you for the advice, gentlemen. I'm trying to get my rep up and get the hang of this whole thing.

Comment: take it easy.  Everyone (incl me) has experience receiving downvotes because of some sounds-invalid reasons.  However this is the spirit of community-maintained site.  Just keep on contributing and you will see your rep grow :)  Good work :) wish to see more contribution from you :)

Comment: Thank you! I will keep it up; I've benefited a lot from SO and feel that I am semi-knowledgeable enough about some things to give back now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `charAt` on a floating point variable (or any other data type other than `String`s).  (Unless you define a `charAt` method for your own classes...)

You can, however, convert that floating point number to a string and check the `charAt(str.length()-1)`.

Comment: You can't use `charAt` with an integer, decimal, timer, JFrame or anything else either. "charAt can only be used on strings" is more correct. (nitpicking, I know. But the way it's currently stated indicates that the 'floating point' is key here).

Comment: `charAt(str.length)` will produce `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your float variable to string and use `charAt(strVar.length - 1)`.

```
double a=5.51123123;
String strVar=String.valueOf(a);
System.out.print(strVar.charAt(strVar.length -1);
```

Comment: `float a=5.51123123;` will **not** compile.

Comment: Then you can use double or any other type which you required. Never expect 100% exact result on post. I gave a logic to do it.

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks for your comment. but i was try to post solution at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function simply and you can customize data types accordingly,

```
private int getLastDigit(double val){
    String tmp = String.valueOf(val);
    return Integer.parseInt(tmp.substring(tmp.length()-1));
}
```

Comment: Real numbers include floating point values, too.  This would not cover all real numbers.

Comment: Whoops -- I misread the code.  I saw the `Integer.parseInt()` and was mistaken as to what that was doing.  My mistake!

Comment: of course @bstempi, you may change it as getLastDigit(float val) and pass any float value (ex: 3.45678f) now it will return last digit as int. if you need to change return type then before return you must parse it to return type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Double doubleNo = 5.51123123;
String stringNo = doubleNo.toString();
System.out.println(stringNo.charAt(stringNo.length()-1));
```